# Cannot set "Part title font" in Eclipse on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, font-size

Every font in Eclipse looks great, but the titles of tabs are bigger than I would prefer. I attempt to change it but Eclipse doesn't recognize the change. To make a change, I navigate to Preferences-> General-> Appearance-> Font and Colors. I edit "Part title font" but the change doesn't remain, even though the preview is OK.

Comment: Did you try restarting Eclipse after editing the "Part title font" and applying the changes?

Comment: @garycomtois Yes but the "strange" thing is that the font is set to 9px for example but it shown like 14px.

Answer (score 11):

if you are on Linux which is using GTK for eclipse, you can change the file ${ECLIPSE_PATH}/plugin/org.eclipse.platform_${version}/css/e4_default_gtk.css.
If you are on other OS you can also find corresponding css files.

find

```
.MPartStack {
    font-size: 11;
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

change the font-size to 9 or other size you want. After restart eclipse, the view title bar font size will be changed.

Comment: One solution is to simply commenting out the font size line in this file. That seems to give the same font size as in the rest of the system.

Answer (score 4):

First the solution:

I "solved" the problem for myself by following [this advice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Eclipse#Eclipse_4.2.0_not_respecting_dark.2Fcustom_gtk_themes_resulting_in_white_background) from the very bottom of the ArchLinux wiki page for Eclipse and removing all the .css files from /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_{version number}/css/

This allowed my GTK theme to take full control and set all colors and font sizes, which is what I wanted.

If you want to delve deeper into the root cause of this issue, here are some links I located:

- [Bug 344234 - DBCS4.1 Can not change View Title Fonts in
  preference](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344234)
- [Change Eclipse “Part Title Font” (Version 4.2)](http://www.xyzhou.com/it-lives/change-eclipse-part-title-font-version-4-2.html)
- [Eclipse4/CSS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS)

That last page may be a bit confusing. The bottom line is that they've moved to a whole new theming system and left in broken options for reasons I will likely never understand.

For more information, just Google "[theming eclipse 4 with css](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=theming%20eclipse%204%20with%20css)".